# Terminology for multidimensional Fourier series

Tags: terminology, fourier-series

Dear All,
I'm computing multidimensional Fourier series of a function $f$ defined on $(0, L_1)\times(0, L_2)\times\cdots\times(0,L_d)$.
The series reads

$f(\vec x)=\sum_{\vec k}\hat f(\vec k)\exp(\imath\vec k\cdot\vec x)$

where the sum is extended to all

$\vec k = \dfrac{2\pi a_1}{L_1}\vec e_1+\cdots+\dfrac{2\pi a_d}{L_d}\vec e_d\qquad(a_1, \ldots, a_d\in\mathbb Z).$

My question is: how do you call the set of the vectors $\vec k$. I think specialists in diffraction would call this set "reciprocal lattice"; how about mathematicians?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Sebastien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually called the *dual lattice* $\hat{\Lambda}$ of the lattice $\Lambda = L_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus L_2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus L_{d} \mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. See [this Wikipedia page on the reciprocal lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice#Generalization_of_a_dual_lattice) for further explanation and have also a look at the one on [Pontryagin duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I'm not allowed to vote you up...